# Flair/Badge for arXiv paper?

Tags: arxiv, open-access, online-publication, open-science

This is borderline trivial, but in my attempt to publish my work in a public repository, I've found badges at the top of my `README.md` to be useful. For example, using [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/), I can create a badge that points to a proper DOI that looks like this:

[image: DOI]
*Encyclopedia of Finite Graphs*

If I have a critical piece of code, I can publish [`Travis.CL`](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/status-images/) badges or [`Coveralls`](https://coveralls.io/) for code coverage.

Is the an equivalent badge or icon I can use to visually indicate that the work has been published on the [`arXiv`](http://arxiv.org/)?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Feel free to make one!

Comment: I don't get what do you want. An icon? Something else?

Comment: By the way, ideally the alt text in the Zenodo badge would give the actual DOI, rather than just saying "DOI," so it would be more convenient for copying/pasting or screen readers.  (But this may not be under your control.)

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician That's a good point and I'll mention it to them. The markdown is copied from their "badge creator" so it shouldn't be hard for them to fix it (and trivial for me to do it on my side).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found a service that can create custom badges: [`shields.io`](http://shields.io/). Using the arXiv background color (Firebrick `#B31B1B`) I was able to create a badge that looked more or less "official". An example of their template and my specific use case:

```
http://img.shields.io/badge/<SUBJECT>-<STATUS>-<COLOR>.svg
http://img.shields.io/badge/math.CO-arXiv%3A1408.3644-B31B1B.svg
```

After converting the svg to png for use on github, I got this:

[image: 1408.3644]

Comment: Minor nitpick: arXiv:1408.3644 is not a DOI, just an arXiv identifier. Do not label it as one.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thanks for the nit-pick, I thought that _was_ the DOI (this is my first submission to the arXiv). It looks like the DOI is reserved for when you publish in a peer-reviewed journal. I've updated the badge to reflect the category instead.

Comment: DOI does not imply a peer-reviewed journal. It's just an identifies that happens to be used by many journals. A publication at arXiv could have DOI and other identifiers (ISBN, URN...) as well.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there's any. As well, I think you want to make one visually matching the ones you already have.

There's an XCF (GIMP) file for the arXiv community ad: 
 http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11924/43247

I think it could be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've done just that and I've shared the result as an answer. After the moderation period ends I'm going to accept my answer. Hopefully it will help someone else down the line.

Answer (score 2):

To add on to the [OP's own answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/27376/122278), it is also possible to use a logo from [Simple Icons](https://simpleicons.org/) (which has an [arXiv icon](https://simpleicons.org/icons/arxiv.svg)) in a badge generated by [shields.io](https://shields.io/). A number of other parameters can also be specified by adding keyword/value pairs after a `?` in the request URL:

`https://img.shields.io/badge/<SUBJECT>-<IDENTIFIER>-<COLOR>?logo=<SIMPLEICONS NAME>&logoColor=<LOGO COLOR>`

Omitting any parameter will set it to its default. Some other possibly useful parameters include `logoWidth` (specified in pixels), `style` (default is `flat`), and `labelColor` (to change  the color of the lefthand portion of the badge from the default `gray`).

Using `math.CO`, `1408.3644`, and `b31b1b` as the subject, arXiv identifier, and primary color, and setting `logo=arxiv` and `logoColor=red`, we get a badge that looks like this:

[image: arXiv:1408.3644]

Of course, you can compose it however you'd like in practice.